# Workflow that is started by the information management policy is not starting

Tags: sharepoint-server, retention, information-policy

I have a rule on a document library, set on Document and Excel types, to run a workflow. The workflow is meant to move the item to Drop Off and then process it from there. The workflow however is never triggered, am I missing something?

The timer job seems to have run but I still do not see any results:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the conditions of your workflow? Make sure your workflow was created correctly.

By default, Information management policy timer job and Expiration policy timer job run weekly, you need to run them manually in CA to make them run immediately.

Also try to use "Content Types" like below:

[image]

Comment: Hi my problem is that the rule is not even kicking the workflow.... I have a policy that if the modified date is a day ago, then kick workflow to do something, but the workflow is never triggered...